# How do you get the author date and commit date from a JGit RevCommit?

Tags: git, jgit

`RevCommit` has a `getCommitTime()` method but it returns an `int` and it does not have an author time.  How can I get the author and commit date from a `RevCommit`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Like so:

```
RevCommit commit = ...;

PersonIdent authorIdent = commit.getAuthorIdent();
Date authorDate = authorIdent.getWhen();
TimeZone authorTimeZone = authorIdent.getTimeZone();

PersonIdent committerIdent = commit.getCommitterIdent();
...
```

Also see [API documentation](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevCommit.html#getAuthorIdent%28%29).